# How to get value from row above if the condition is true and add one - python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have sorted data like this:

```
Id
A
A
B
C
D
D
D
D
E
```

and I need to check if value one row above is the same. If it isn't, in new column ['value'] should get value 1 but if it is new column should be ['value'] + 1.

I started from doing new column ['Previous_id'] and using .shift()

```
df['Previous_id'] = df['Id'].shift(1)
```

So I get frame like this:

```
Id  Previous_id 
A     Nan             
A     A           
B     A           
C     B           
D     C           
D     D           
D     D           
D     D           
E     D
```

But if I'm trying use .shift in function

```
def func1(row):
    if row['Id'] != row['Previous_id']:
        return 1
    else:
        return row['value'].shift(1) + 1

df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row: func1(row), axis=1)
```

I get an error:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'shift'

I'm looking for solution like this:

Example:

```
Id  Previous_id value
A     Nan             1
A     A           2
B     A           1
C     B           1
D     C           1
D     D           2
D     D           3
D     D           4
E     D           1
```

Comment: In the row `return row['value'].shift(1) + 1`, you are trying to shift `row['value']`, which is `int`, hence the error

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what an error says